# Do IF and Compute in spss macros

Tags: macros, spss

I have the following spss syntax:

```
DO IF SYSMIS(V5).
 COMPUTE V5 = LAG(V5).
END IF.
EXE.
```

It works fine. However I'd like to repeat the same process for several variables. I tried to write a macro to achieve this but I keep getting error messages. This was my attempt:

```
define filldown (!positional !cmdend).
  do if sysmis(!1).
   compute !1 = lag (!1).
  end if.
  execute.
!enddefine.

!filldown V5 age wt htm.
```

How do I write a macro that will work (I'm new to macros)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@horace_vr's `do repeat` solution is definitely the right approach for this case.
The following is just to learn something about macros while you're at it.

First of all, you can use your present macro for each variable separately, but you need to use the original macro call (don't add "!"), so:

```
filldown V5.
filldown age.
....
```

But of course you can create a loop within the macro, like this:

```
define filldown (!positional !cmdend).
!do !vr !in (!1)
  do if sysmis(!vr).
   compute !vr = lag (!vr).
  end if.
  execute.
!doend
!enddefine.
```

Now you can use the macro call once with the complete list:

```
filldown V5 age wt htm.
```

Answer (score 2):

The macro is simply a text substitution function. It will literally replace your `!1` with whatever argument you are providing when calling the macro (`V5 age wt htm`).

To keep things simple, I would recommend using a simple `do repeat` command, instead of a macro, which may be little uncomfortable to use if you are not familiar with them

```
do repeat varlist=V5 age wt htm.
if sysmis(varlist) varlist=lag(varlist).
end repeat.
exe.
```

P.S.: If you really want to use your macro, you need to call it for each variable separately.

Comment: I would have done a do repeat but the variables are not contiguous. Moreover, I'd like to use the macro call several times in the analysis.

Comment: the variables specified in a `do repeat` structure do not have to be consecutive. If they are consecutive, you can specify them like `var1 to varn`; if they are not consecutive, you simply specify them explicitly, like I did in my asnwer; `V5` , `age`, `wt` and `htm` can be anywhere in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Set Auto sum To lisp. Other variables cannot be quantified. A quantifier is a lisp command which shows the next sum of the program.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have made changes to my answers.

Comment: "answers" yes. What is the purpose of having two posts. Please consider deleting one and merging both into one.

Answer (score -1):

Fill ! V2 you need to call V before rv,
V2 is positional, that is command is read only after changes has been made.
Define filldown ! v5
do! rv! fill! V2
..........
End